# Copy Files into Sharepoint

Tags: trigger, sharepoint

We need to have a way to copy a File into SharePoint folder as soon as it is created.

From my sandbox, I connected to SP with the new "SharePoint connect" feature.
Is there a way to create a Trigger which will detect when a new file is created and then will copy it into the external SP source ?

Answer (score 0):

You can user the after insert trigger on Attachement.

Comment: Txs for the tip but it does the trigger give me access the the file or is it just a notification. At the end of the day, I need to copy it to the external source.